# Using python I would like to know if one point (with three coordinates) is closer to 2 cm of other point given

Tags: python, math, bioinformatics, computational-geometry

I have two `numpy.ndarray` like this, but with many more rows:

```
A = numpy.array([[7.087,  0.038, -130.550],
                 [0.073,  1.224,  -13.257]])

B = numpy.array([[20.047, -0.038, -12.551],
                 [16.073,  1.224,  13.257]])
```

Each row is one point, each element is x, y, z in the space.

How can I determine how many points are closer than 2 cm?

I have though different ways to solve this problem. One could be creating a sphere with radius = 2. If one point of A is in the sphere of one point of B, means they are closer than 2 cm.

I think I could create a program to solve this but I am not sure how I can know the number of the total points when one point of A is closer than 2 or more points of B because what I want is the total number of points closer I mean the sum of A and B that are closer than 2 cm.

Comment: Does it need to be fast? If not, you could to a nested loop and just compare each one with the other

Comment: I am new in python so I don't know how I can compare two-point with a two cm difference.

Comment: So for each point in A, you want all the points in B that are within 2cm?

Comment: Yes and finally to know the total number of points which means the number of point that are closer than 2

Comment: By the way I have find a formula that could work 
(x - cx)^2 + (y - cy)^2 + (z - cz)^2 < r^2 being x, y and z point A and cx, cy and cz the point B

Comment: So also the points in A that are closer than 2cm to other points in A, and similarly for B?

Comment: yes. that part of the problem confuses me because I dont know how I can distinguish that. I dont want to count the same point twice or more.
For that reason I thing with the sphere I opnly need to count the point A plus the number of points B that are inside the sphere A right?

Comment: Is this the question or did I misinterpret:

Find all points in A that are closer than 2cm to at least one point in B?

So will A and B be each a list of tuples with X,Y,Z .

Do you have to read A and B from a text file?

Comment: Your title doesn't match the question. And, honestly, your question is quite confuse.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a vectorized approach using `numpy`.  It creates an `N_a`-by-`3`-by-`N_b` array that is basically the Cartesian product of all elements of `a` and `b`.  Then, it uses the `numpy.linalg.norm` function to compute the Euclidean norm over the axis corresponding to length `3`.

```
import numpy

a = numpy.array([
    [7.9,  0.0, -130.6],
    [0.1,  1.2,  -13.3]
])

b = numpy.array([
    [20.0,  -0.0,  -12.6],
    [16.1,   1.2,   13.3],
    [ 0.5,   1.5,  -12.0],
    [ 8.0,   1.0, -131.0],
])

RADIUS = 2.0
d = a[:, :, numpy.newaxis] - b[:, :, numpy.newaxis].T  #  shape: (2, 3, 4)
close = numpy.linalg.norm(d, ord=2, axis=1) < RADIUS

# Result:
#   array([[False, False, False,  True],
#          [False, False,  True, False]])
```

`close` is a Boolean array, indexed by the indices of `a` and `b` respectively, where `close[i][j]` indicates whether `a[i]` and `b[j]` are close points.

To count the number of close points, you can simply sum over the appropriate axis:

```
a_close_count = numpy.sum(close, axis=-1)
# Result: 
#   array([1, 1])

b_close_count = numpy.sum(close, axis=0)
# Result:
#   array([0, 0, 1, 1])
```

If you just need to check whether a point in `a` or `b` is close to *any* point in the other array, you can replace `numpy.sum` with `numpy.any` in the expressions above.

Answer (score -2):

I guess I'd go for a scipy distance matrix: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance_matrix.html

Comment: To those who downvoted my answer: Could you please clarify why it's wrong or a bad option? It would be extremely nice to know.